# Can i install android studio on a 32 bit machine?

Tags: android, android-studio

Can i install android-studio on windows 7 32 bit operating system with 1gb of ram?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1. This is offtopic for this site. The distribution site should have system requirements. 2. I'd bet the 1gb of RAM will be more of a problem than the architecture of the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can according to [Android studio official site](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) in System Requirements. There is Windows 64 or 32-bit. For Linux it was tested on 64 distro only.